# continously share a texture between two process directx 11

Tags: c++, directx

I am sharing a rendered output from Process A to Process B using a shared NT handle in Directx 11, for this I am using CreateSharedHandle and OpenSharedResourceByName by giving same name to both...

problem is it is not continuously updating texture in process B which use a textured quad full screen to draw a shared texture...

how this can be done efficiently ...

process A

```html
IDXGIResource1* pResource;
                pTexture->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIResource1), (void**)&pResource);
                SAFE_RELEASE(pTexture);

                if (g_texSharedHandle == nullptr)
                {
                    hr = pResource->CreateSharedHandle(NULL, DXGI_SHARED_RESOURCE_READ | DXGI_SHARED_RESOURCE_WRITE, TEXT("MySurface"), &g_texSharedHandle);
                    if (FAILED(hr))
                    {
                        MessageBoxA(nullptr, "CreateSharedHandle failed!", "Error", MB_OK);
                    }
                }
```

Process B

```html
hr = g_pd3dDevice1->OpenSharedResourceByName( TEXT("MySurface"), DXGI_SHARED_RESOURCE_READ, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (void**)&g_pTexture2D);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        MessageBoxA(nullptr, "opening OpenSharedResourceByName failed!", "Error", MB_OK);
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide snippets of the shared handle creation, opening, and update? If it turns out to be dependent on some details, seeing what you are using will greatly help.

Comment: Process A `IDXGIResource1* pResource;
                pTexture->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIResource1), (void**)&pResource);
                SAFE_RELEASE(pTexture);

                if (g_texSharedHandle == nullptr)
                {
                    hr = pResource->CreateSharedHandle(NULL, DXGI_SHARED_RESOURCE_READ | DXGI_SHARED_RESOURCE_WRITE, TEXT("MySurface"), &g_texSharedHandle);
                    if (FAILED(hr))
                    {
                        MessageBoxA(nullptr, "CreateSharedHandle failed!", "Error", MB_OK);
                    }
                }`

Comment: Process B `hr = g_pd3dDevice1->OpenSharedResourceByName( TEXT("MySurface"), DXGI_SHARED_RESOURCE_READ, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (void**)&g_pTexture2D);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        MessageBoxA(nullptr, "opening OpenSharedResourceByName failed!", "Error", MB_OK);
        return;
    }`

Comment: both are in their loop

Comment: any one???.........

Comment: Not my area, but if I had to dig... Where in the doc does it says that the texture should/would update? "Open shared resource" feel like just "open and read", I don't see any obvious statement that this API is meant to continuously update